# bibliography style without listing all references

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I'm used to using templates and cls files for writing papers and many of them automatically provide a bibliography style where the references are listed i.e. rather than [[1], [2], [3]] when I write \cite{refa,refb,refc} the output is [[1]-[3]] which is preferable for me. My current latex reads:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage[margin=2.10cm,footskip=1.5cm]{geometry} % See geometry.pdf to learn the layout options. There are lots.
\usepackage[nouppercase]{scrpage2}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\geometry{a4paper} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
```

and my bibliography style is

```
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
```

and I get the style [[1], [2], [3]] when I list references. Any advice on what to change to make the refernecing [[1],[3]] while of course listing all refernces in the bibliography would begreat

Comment: `\usepackage[sort&compress]{natbib}` with `\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}` should work, or maybe just `\usepackage[compress]{natbib}` (still with `\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}`).

Comment: that works nicely thank you!